# Get best synonym for words in sentences using wordnet

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I have done code to get synonyms from wordnet, and it is providing complete list of synonym for each word.
So, I want my code to select appropriate synonym from synonym list based on sentence.

For example: 
Sentence is: "I am his older brother" and I have to find out best synonym for each word based on this sentence.

Lets select "older". Wordnet would give synonym list for "older":

*['elder', 'onetime', 'former', 'sr.', 'one-time', 'erstwhile', 'honest-to-god', 'aged', 'Old', 'previous', 'sure-enough', 'older', 'senior', 'old', 'sometime', 'honest-to-goodness', 'quondam', 'elderly']*

From the list best synonym based on this sentence is 'elder', so it should be selected.

How can I do this?

Code to get synonyms:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

def tag(sentence):
 words = word_tokenize(sentence)
 words = pos_tag(words)
 return words

def paraphraseable(tag):
 return tag.startswith('NN') or tag == 'VB' or tag.startswith('JJ')

def pos(tag):
 if tag.startswith('NN'):
  return wn.NOUN
 elif tag.startswith('V'):
  return wn.VERB

def synonyms(word, tag):
    lemma_lists = [ss.lemmas() for ss in wn.synsets(word, pos(tag))]
    lemmas = [lemma.name() for lemma in sum(lemma_lists, [])]
    return set(lemmas)

def synonymIfExists(sentence):
 for (word, t) in tag(sentence):
   if paraphraseable(t):
    syns = synonyms(word, t)
    if syns:
     if len(syns) > 1:
      yield [word, list(syns)]
      continue
   yield [word, []]

def paraphrase(sentence):
 return [x for x in synonymIfExists(sentence)]
get=[]
get=paraphrase("I am his older brother")
print("paraphrase",get)
```

Comment: Why is "elder" the best? (I.e. what is the criteria to judge best, or what algorithm are you using to decide this?)  (Incidentally, I'd have thought "big brother" was the best synonym for "older brother", but you didn't even get that in your list!)

Answer (score 2):

Synonyms in synsets are listed irrespective of their frequency of occurrence in natural language and in a given context. 
To explore both of these missing areas more I would go for an bi-gram predictive model and check what words from the synset appear as next to the left context of the utterance you want to substitute it in. Similarly, you could explore right context as well and/or longer contexts.

Another (easier) approach would be to introduce frequency order to the WordNet based on word frequencies from a large enough corpus. Assumption would be that frequency of appearance in the corpus is a correct hint for perceived suitability of a synonym.